# Sitecollection Overview Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sitecollection

I have the following situation:

- MOSS 2007 Server Environment A -> Intranet
- MOSS 2007 Server Environment B -> Collaboration Environment (approx. 150 site collections for various issues)

Both environments are on different infrastructures but we use the same Active Directory and the same groups. Now we would like to implement the following 2 things:

- An overview page within the intranet with all available site collections on environment b.
- An overview page within the intranet with only those site collections the user has access on.

now i'm searching for some good ideas what would be the best way to realise something like this.

thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to be careful of in a solution like this is performance, particularly for your second requirement. That would require looping through every site collection and retrieving permission data, either using the web services or the object model.

I would recommend writing a [**custom timer job**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686.aspx) (or two for each requirement if that makes more sense) to execute at a low-traffic time and aggregate this information for storage in a **custom SQL database**. If there is never low traffic then delay your requests to reduce impact on the server.

A **custom web part** (or again, two if more appropriate) can then be deployed to both environments. The web part would query the database for the required information and display it to the user.

If the timer job needs to update this data more frequently then you would need to implement some sort of in-memory caching. Depending on your requirements this may need a lot of memory.